# Create self contained class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a special model in my app that doesn't require a hash to be sent on creation or on updating, so I would like to create an abstract model that would override the necessary methods of ApplicationRecord to not require any hash to be passed on update or on creation. I've come up with this so far:

```
class SelfContained < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  def create
    object = new(attributes)
    object.save
    object
  end

  def create!
    object = new(attributes)
    object.save
    object
  end

  def update
    with_transaction_returning_status do
      assign_attributes(attributes)
      save
    end
  end

  def update!
    with_transaction_returning_status do
      assign_attributes(attributes)
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

and then models that want to implement this can:

```
class ModelName < SelfContained
  private

  def attribute
    get_data_from_outside
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that it partially works. The following cases won't work:

```
ModelName.create # create directly. This should work with ModelName.create(*association_ids)
ModelName.update # update directly. This should work with ModelName.update(id)

parent = ParentModel.find 1; parent.create_model_name
```

I've searched all the web for this and I'm not finding anything that can help me.

Comment: What do you mean, "won't work"?

Comment: It's bypassing... I can send a hash.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `get_data_from_outside` is a method that calls an external API or something along that line?

Comment: @jvillian Yes, exactly!

Comment: I would suggest, then, that you rethink your approach. IMO, classes that inherit from ApplicationRecord should be for interacting with the database *only*. AR classes already have a lot of responsibility (before you add a single line of code) and you're only loading on top of that. So, perhaps consider creating a service object that interacts with the "outside" (whatever that may be) and that interacts with your AR class in a more conventional manner.

Comment: Perhaps look at ActiveModel or https://github.com/rails/activeresource as your base class?

Comment: @jvillian I will happily follow your advice. I was already feeling that it was a bad idea to mess up with AR haha

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the whole idea is mislead. If you want to create a resource that is only created from something like an API call and not user input then don't expose it with a route.

Having models that do not correspond to a route/controller is completely normal and if you're worried that someone might in be able to create/update one of those records you should really invest in tests that cover that instead of changing the whole interface of ActiveRecord.

The change itself to the class itself by making it "self-contained" is actually not a positive one either as you're destroying the linear flow.

```
@thing = Thing.create(foo: 'bar')
assert_equals('bar', @thing.foo)
```

This is pretty easy both to follow and test.

Now if we change Thing into an instance of your SelfContained class the outcome actually depends on what the internal method returns. This is actually a huge step backwards when it comes to readability and and testability.

Not to mention that both `attribute` and `attributes` are both method names reserved by ActiveModel and ActiveRecord.

As @jvillian mentioned doing HTTP calls or any other kind of "imports" from an external source will just further bloat your model. You most likely want a client class (which does HTTP calls) combined with a service object (that calls the client and turns the result into models).

Comment: Yep, totally agreed... I had the idea and though "THAT'S A GREAT IDEA", but then I realized it was shit as hell hahaha. I'm doing exactly that, I have a service now that's responsible for calling an internal SDK